# Can I select a container image from private ECR repository in my CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hi I was wondering if it would be possible to select a docker imagem from my private respository in ECR using cloud formation yml for later use when configuring my task definition on an ECS service, something like this:

```
  ContainerImage:
    Description: "Container image"
    Type: AWS::ECR::PrivateRepository
```

Comment: Not sure what do you mean. There is no such thing as `AWS::ECR::PrivateRepository`.

Comment: I'd like to select an ECR image from a list and use it on my ECS Task Definition

Comment: How did it go? Still not sure what you can do?

Comment: Didn't use it, but your answer was very helpful, I didn't know that it was possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is by development of a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The resource would be a lambda function which would use AWS SDK, such as boto3, to query your ECR, and return a list of available images to your stack for further use.